# Writing from JS to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JavaScript file:

```
export default {
  'test/index.yaml': {
    name: 'Test Index',
    product: 'test'
  },
  'test/hello.yaml': {
    name: 'Test Greeting',
    product: 'test'
  } 
}
```

I am looking to convert this into a JSON file with the desired output being:

```
{
  "test/index.yaml": {
    "name": "Test Index",
    "product": "test"
  },
  "test/hello.yaml": {
    "name": "Test Greeting",
    "product": "test"
  }
}
```

--

I am trying to use something like this:

```
fs.readFileSync('test/configuration.js').toString().split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
    fs.appendFileSync('newTest/configuration.json', JSON.stringify(line) + '\n');
});
```

But it doesn't break into the correct JSON syntax with the output of:

```
"export default {"
"  'test/index.yaml': {"
"    name: 'Test Index',"
"    product: 'test'"
"  },"
"  'test/hello.yaml': {"
"    name: 'Test Greeting',"
"    product: 'test'"
"  }" 
"}"
```

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Why not just `require()` the file and stringify the exported object?

Comment: Can't you just remove any instance of double quote or "export default" and you are done?

Comment: @JamesGaunt no because the original source is not JSON.

Comment: I meant in your output? Then it would be the same JSON. Actually based on other answers maybe you don't really want JSON (i.e. a string) but a Javascript object - in which case you'd then need to eval the JSON which is probably bad practice.

Comment: Are you using a build tool to convert ES6 `exports` to `module.exports` so that you could simply require the JS file, convert the value to JSON and write that to a file? Trying to convert the JS to JSON by reading the JS as *string* is certainly the wrong approach.

Comment: @JamesGaunt Then name and product wouldn't have `""` - correct ?

Comment: It's not JSON. The property names are not quoted. It's JavaScript, but not JSON.

Comment: Ah yes good point - didn't spot that. So you could "require" the file and then JSON.stringify the result?

Comment: I just responded to the answer below with my new code - is that correct (doesn't correctly space out the file, with new lines - but seems to grab the data correctly)

Comment: @NikkiNelson: If you want the JSON to be formatted, you can pass an indent as third argument: `JSON.stringify(value, null, 2)`. But yes, that's how you would do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
//'somefile.js'
module.exports = {
  'test/index.yaml': {
    name: 'Test Index',
    product: 'test'
  },
  'test/hello.yaml': {
    name: 'Test Greeting',
    product: 'test'
  }
}
```

Your script:

```
let obj = require(__dirname + '/somefile.js');
console.log(obj);
//{ 'test/index.yaml': { name: 'Test Index', product: 'test' },
//  'test/hello.yaml': { name: 'Test Greeting', product: 'test' } }

fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('somefile.json', JSON.stringify(obj), function (err) {
  if(err) console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: So would the code look like this:
`const obj = require('./SWAGGER_CONFIG.js');

fs.appendFileSync('_data/SWAGGER_CONFIG.json', JSON.stringify(obj) + '\n');`

Comment: @NikkiNelson: If `./SWAGGER_CONFIG.js` doesn't use `export default` (but `module.exports`) then yes.

Comment: This still doesn't do what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @Felic Kling there you go :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called [json5](http://json5.org/) which does exactly this, converting things that are valid JavaScript into valid JSON.  From their documentation:

> - Object keys can be unquoted if they’re valid identifiers.
> - Strings can be single-quoted.